# ASPxHtmlEditor disable HTML input

Tags: c#-4.0, devexpress

I want my `ASPxHtmlEditor` to show text as plain text(this is for some requirement where in I will have to disable HTML editor and show text as normal text only for few users). Is it achievable? I have set the `HtmlEditorToolbar` visibility to false. But still if i copy and paste colored text the editor will show the colored text.

If this not achievable only option will be to show a normal aspx text area for few users and DevExpress `ASPxHtmlEditor` editor for other users.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible to use both the ASPxHtmlEditor for the rich text and ASPxMemo/textarea for the plain text.
Perform the necessary checks and decide which control should be shown. Hide another control by setting its Visible property to false.
Then, bind the ASPxHtmlEditor.Html or ASPxMemo.Value property with the corresponding field and display it to an end-user.

P.S. Why don't you contact the DevExpress guys regarding your inquiry?